# AngularJS: cant get ng-if to limit a dataset properly in an ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs-ng-repeat, angular-ng-if

Banging head on wall, when really should be off consuming dangerous amounts of alcohol for the new year. Anyway.

I've recreated a problem I'm having in a project with some nice simple data. I know this must be a simple fix, but I'm not seeing it as I swear my logic is sound.

What I wanted to do, was limit a resultset to a certain amount of rows while using ng-repeat. I placed an ng-if on the data line checking for $index being within a range that I've used a slider/textbox to control. It seems that having an {a < x < b} scenario is somehow causing me grief and it always displays the greater value AFTER the initial load, when its showing a correct data subset.

```
<div ng-repeat="data in dataSet" >
    <div ng-bind="data" ng-if="$index < (model + 5) && $index > (model -5)">
    </div>
</div>
```

Change the slider or the input box and the magic is gone and the thing erupts.

Plunker of the issue.
http://plnkr.co/edit/4JXEp8r72QziRxWODUys

Comment: I have tried with limitTo, and that fails as soon as I alter the limit amount so jimmie it that way, adding a filter-esque function to the scope doesnt work either. it gets upset as soon as there are 2 checks. Might try making a new filter while I await some genius to tell me what I've screwed up.

Comment: ok figured it out. ng-model on the range returns a STRING not an NUMBER. so fast fix is to do a subtraction before adding the limit buffer, thanks javascript. Plunker is fixed with the change. note the model -1 + 5 instead of model + 5. Booya.